# How to sent a GET request of HttpURLConnection with data-urlencode

Tags: java, rest, httpurlconnection, urlencode

I'm using `HttpURLConnection` to sent a GET requisition with `data-urlencode` to Parse.

In the documentation of Parse, it states:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

But I have no idea how to do that in `HttpURLConnection`.
The following is my code:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("X-AVOSCloud-Application-Id", "psohqd1vx5ta2479i130wznpngp19uiuuku36c0s8986ccm0");
            connection.setRequestProperty("X-AVOSCloud-Application-Key", "zf7ol3sit5g2ruy9emm8o62xbi3ozelpt7ipbtt29h9iaw2i");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.connect();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Parse.com right? If so, you should be using `X-Parse-Application-Id` and `X-Parse-REST-API-Key` instead of AVOSCloud keys.